# How to find the Second largest value from a table.?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

One table with EmpSalary in Employee Table. I need to find the second largest Salary what is paid by the company.?

How to find the Second largest value(Salary) from a table.?

Comment: What value do you want returned if there are two records with the equal top value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: this should give the second largest salary:

SELECT MAX(EmpSalary) FROM employee WHERE EmpSalary < (SELECT MAX(EmpSalary) FROM employee);

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking for a very simple answer and not needing CTEs

Comment: There are two queries in this one: the inner query (SELECT MAX(EmpSalary) FROM employee) returns the largest salary. The outer query has a where condition that returns the largest value in the table which is less than value returned by inner query. Since inner query returns largest salary, outer query returns second largest value. Hope I have explained it properly.

Answer (score 7):

```
;WITH CTE AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortColumn DESC) AS RowNumber, * 
               FROM YourTable)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber = 2
```

Comment: Common Table Expression. You can use any name. CTE_SALARY for instance.

Comment: Wats happening here.. wen we running it..??

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) Clause orders your data based on the order by specification and auto-numbers it in 'RowNumber' column. You are then picking the second row from it.

Comment: This is returning the second row but that might not be the second largest salary if more than 1 person has the highest salary as per Askashm's comment on question

Answer (score -1):

select top(1) prodMrp from Product where not prodMrp  = (select top(1) prodMrp from Product order by prodMrp DESC ) order by prodMrp DESC

Comment: If you're gonna copy and paste, at least take the trouble to make it *look* relevant.